# Need to format an array using call_user_func_array php

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to merge an array in loop, for that I am using call_user_func_array method to merge. But when I am trying to merge It holds the value with [0] as well as ['somekey']. But I need to format some other format.

```
$resultSet = array(

   array(

        'id' => 'f205b8ef-c1de-0aa8-687a-50f3d41122a0',
        'name' => 'vijay'
       )
 );

$resultSet['SomeModule'] = call_user_func_array('array_merge',$resultSet);
$resultSet['next_offset'] = '-1';
print_r($resultSet);
```

For the above code I am getting the output as

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => f205b8ef-c1de-0aa8-687a-50f3d41122a0
            [name] => vijay
        )

    [SomeModule] => Array
        (
            [id] => f205b8ef-c1de-0aa8-687a-50f3d41122a0
            [name] => vijay
        )

    [next_offset] => -1
)
```

But I need to get the output as below format

```
Array
(
    [SomeModule] => Array
        (
            [id] => f205b8ef-c1de-0aa8-687a-50f3d41122a0
            [name] => vijay
        )

    [next_offset] => -1
)
```

Anyone cal help me. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

The function returns the merged array and it's being added to the SomeModule key.

[`Array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

> Returns the resulting array.

You should use another variable for your case, for instance: $resultSet2.

```
$resultSet = array(

   array(

        'id' => 'f205b8ef-c1de-0aa8-687a-50f3d41122a0',
        'name' => 'vijay'
       )
 );

$resultSet2['SomeModule'] = call_user_func_array('array_merge',$resultSet);
$resultSet2['next_offset'] = '-1';
print_r($resultSet2);
```